# Using java class in jsp

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, dspace, jspinclude

I have java class having very simple method for database connection. Connection is established while using this code is jsp file but when i call this method from .java class it gives exception. 
the code i use to call that method is as fallow

```
  <% db d = new db();
d.db1("testing", "dspace", "dspace");
  %>
```

while the code is .java class is as fallow

```
 public boolean  db1 (String db, String username, String pwd) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
                       {
            Connection connection; 

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql:5432//127.0.0.1:5432/testing", username,
                pwd);
            if(connection!= null)
                                   {
          System.out.println("done");
            }          
    return false;
    }
```

there error is

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
```

Comment: Is there any more to that stack trace?

Comment: You showed JSP code; show java code from where u calling db1()

Comment: The entire code of class `db` is not mentioned. So I will make some assumptions.  If you have defined a custom constructor, make sure you explicitly put the default no argument constructor.

Comment: java code is also resides their having method db1

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of JSP).

Comment: can you provide more exception stacktrace ?

Comment: "error in javac compilation" is not the *cause* of the error. Please, post the cause, it should be there in the logs/output as well.

Comment: may be you don't have the postgre sql jar file in class path like we have it in mysql.

Comment: You Java code does not make a valid Java class, it only contains a single method declaration. Assuming you are only posting part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<% 
db d ;
try{
d = new db();
d.db1("testing", "dspace", "dspace");
}catch(Exception e){
 //do something
 }
  %>
```

As your code is not handling the runtime exceptions.

Comment: also `<%@page import="your.db.class" %>`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the DB URL be

```
"jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testing"
```

instead of

```
"jdbc:postgresql:5432//127.0.0.1:5432/testing"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a jar mistake i think but please show complete errors list
Like below:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected
```

More detail will ease us to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <% db d = new db();
    try{
       d.db1("testing", "dspace", "dspace");
    }catch(Exception e){
       //wtf?
    }
 %>
```

Even there are some cases not specified.

- What if the connection is broken
- What if the connection is closed
- What if the connection is timedout
- What if the connection is dirty
- What if the database not available anymore
- What if the database removed
- What if the databaseserver not available
- What if the databaseserver timed out
- What if the user not available
- What if the user has no right
- ...

Hey you can get rid of the db.java using jstl/sql and jndi.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so that you used Class.forname in JSP
please try encapsulate